Trying to change the background color of a grid element on click event
I cant seem to figure out the syntax to get an element in my grid to change colors on a click event.  Ive tried a few different iterations of this, and cant seem to figure out what im doing wrong.  Pretty new to javscript so go easy on me if its a very obvious answer.
JS
    const gridContainer = document.getElementById('container');

    function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
      gridContainer.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
      gridContainer.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);

      for (i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
        let cell = document.createElement('div');
        gridContainer.appendChild(cell).className = 'grid-item';
      }
    }
    makeGrid(16, 16);

    const gridElement = document.getElementById('grid-item');
    gridElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        gridElement.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    })

css
:root {
    --grid-cols: 1;
    --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container{
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0em;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
    background-color: black;
}

.grid-item{
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #131313;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}



const gridContainer = document.getElementById('container');

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
  gridContainer.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  gridContainer.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);

  for (i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement('div');
    gridContainer.appendChild(cell).className = 'grid-item';
  }
}
makeGrid(16, 16);

const gridElement = document.getElementById('grid-item');
gridElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
  gridElement.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
})
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  background-color: black;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #131313;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
<div id="container"></div>



I tried to make a separate function to target the grid element and on clicking the element the color would change but it doesnt seem to click.

You are assigning the class grid-item to your cells, but then looking up the element by id. Try this to get all elements with the grid-item class: var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');. Then loop through all the grid-item elements and add your click event listener to each.

I adapted your code to display/function as a running example; you didn't post any HTML, so I took the liberty of adding a <div> with the id of container to the code you shared. If this is inaccurate please [edit] the question so that it accurately reflects your code.

First, grid-item is not an element id to query with getElementById, but is class, you can use getElementsByClassName or querySelectorAll.
I prefer the querySelectorAll as it could be used for any selector, but keep in mind that it return a NodeList, which you need to iterate over to apply the click event in each item.
    const gridElements = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');

    gridElements.forEach(gridElement => {
      gridElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        gridElement.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      })
    })


Wanted to come back and say thank you for the tip, JavaScript was not making much sense to me and for some reason that bade it click for me! So thanks again!

You have 256 elements that have the class grid-item but you are getting them by id.
Try this document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => el.style.backgroundColor = 'white'));
